Cycles adds a thousand or so child hairs
Blender 4.2.1 using the Geometry Node hair.  I added eyelashes to a character.  In eevee they look as expected in render:

If I change to Cycles, suddenly it looks like there are about a thousand child hairs for every guide hair:

This happens with both Principled BSDF and Principled Hair BSDF shaders, in spite of the docs saying Principled Hair doesn't work with eevee.  I didn't add child hairs anywhere I can see, or at least there are none in the modifier stack:

Anyone know where all the child hairs came from?  Is there a hidden setting somewhere that does this?

I guess it's not children what you see here. It's very thick hair because you have not set the radius. Related questions https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/311242/107598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210751/107598 - In Blender 3.x, the options for the viewport is now called Cycles render properties > Curves > Viewport Display > Shape or Eevee render properties > Curves > Shape. Set it to Strip to see the actual thickness in the viewport. Then open the asset browser and add a Set Hair Curve Profile modifier to your curves object to control the thickness of the hair.

In Blender 4.2.1, the answer turns out to be to add a Set Hair Curve Profile moderator to the Curves, then set the radius to .0002 m.
